# When using styles to move buttons, the 'hotspot' remains in place but the buttons moves

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When using styles to move buttons where I want them, the touchable area where you can press the button remains in the same place and doesn't follow the button. This makes the button unresponsive and can only be pressed if you find the original location!

I've tried:

- using TouchableWithoutFeedback.
- Moving the order of the components
- Putting all sorts in the style reference.

Here's the render:

```
render() {

if((this.state.isOn) === true){

    return(
      <ImageBackground source={require('./assets/water-in-glass.gif')} style={styles.container}>

      <Text>Timer:{ms(this.state.time,{verbose: true})}</Text>

  <TouchableOpacity
     onPressIn={this.onItemMouseDown} 
     onPressOut={this.onItemMouseUp}
     >
     <View>
     <Image source={require('./assets/MyButton.png')}/>

      </View>

      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
     onPress={this.resetTimer}
     >
     <View>
     <View style={styles.resetbutton}> 
       <Text style={styles.text}>Reset Timer</Text>
       </View> 
       </View>
     </TouchableOpacity>
     <TouchableOpacity
     onPress={this.onSubmit} 
     >
     <View>
     <View style={styles.submitbutton}>
     <Text style={styles.text}>Done!</Text>
     </View>
     </View>

     </TouchableOpacity>
    </ImageBackground>

    )
      } else if ((this.state.isOn) === false){  

    return(
      <ImageBackground source={require('./assets/water-in-glass.gif')} style={styles.container}>


     <Text>Timer:{ms(this.state.time)}</Text>  

     <TouchableOpacity
     onPressIn={this.onItemMouseDown} 
     onPressOut={this.onItemMouseUp}
     >
     <View>
     <Image source={require('./assets/MyButton.png')}/>
     </View>      
     </TouchableOpacity>

     <TouchableOpacity
     onPress={this.resetTimer}
     >
     <View>
     <View style={styles.resetbutton}> 
       <Text style={styles.text}>Reset Timer</Text>
       </View> 
       </View>
     </TouchableOpacity>
     <TouchableOpacity
     onPress={this.onSubmit} 
     >
     <View>
     <View style={styles.submitbutton}>
     <Text style={styles.text}>Done!</Text>
     </View>
     </View>

     </TouchableOpacity>

      {this.state.scoreArray.map(function(item,i){

        return (i < 5) ? <Text key={i}>{item}</Text> : null}).filter(x=>x)

        }

        <Text>
        {this.state.animalArray.map(function(item,i){

          return (i < 5) ? <Text key={i}>{item}</Text> : null}).filter(x=>x)
        }
        </Text>


  </ImageBackground>
```

here's the styling:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  pissbutton: {

    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: '#111'
  },
  resetbutton: {

    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 3,
    backgroundColor: '#ed1c42'
  },
  submitbutton: {

    marginBottom: 36,
    top: 100,
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 3,
    backgroundColor: '#42f471'
  }
});
```

I expect when I use styling to move the buttons, they remain responsive, instead of moving, but the hotspot remaining where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it.

The button needed it's own container:

```
submitbuttoncontainer:{
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 50,
  },
  submitbutton: {

    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 12,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: 100,
    alignItems: 'center',


  }
```

Wow. That's totally not clear anywhere. I suspect it's my lack of basic knowledge in coding.